# TransferQueue without duplicates

Tags: java, collections, concurrency, queue

I need to use **TransferQueue without duplicates** (LinkedTransferQueue for example or others).

Is this code safe when the items is added to the queue by producers from different threads and this code will be executed by each producer thread? If not, how to implement the correct solution to this problem?

```
TransferQueue<String> queue = /* for example queue from object constructor */;
if(!queue.contains("hello")) {
    queue.transfer("hello");
}
```

Comment: No, this is obviously incorrect, a typical case of the “check-then-act” antipattern. There is no guaranty that the condition doesn’t change between the `contains` call and the `transfer` call. There’s also the semantic problem: Why do you think, “*queue contains `"hello"` (but might be removed the next nanosecond)*” is a fundamentally different case than “*`"hello"` has been removed a nanosecond ago*”?

Comment: @Holger I thought about it and thought there are universal solutions for unique values in the queue

Comment: In case of `LinkedTransferQueue`, the only built-in `TransferQueue`, [not even the `size()` operation is cheap](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html#:~:text=the%20size%20method%20is%20NOT%20a%20constant%2Dtime%20operation). So what would you expect about tracking duplicates within a queue, especially when you can not even name an actual use case for such a feature?

Comment: @Holger that's a scroll to text fragment! that's amazing. sorry for the off-top.

Comment: @Eugene on the other hand, it’s a bit surprising that it took almost 30 years to invent such a feature, given that the need to link to documents without an appropriate anchor exists since day one.